# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm working on updating the options for a project. Nothing in the code changes, we just create a new options class and update the information. While testing I cam across this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Genetics.Meeting.Abstracts.Services.AbstractsService' while
> attempting  to activate 'Genetics.Meeting.Abstracts.Controllers.Abstract'.

This is a controller in another project that this project references. I haven't made any code changes there.

```
    private AbstractsService _service;
    
    public Abstract(AbstractsService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
```

That is the code referencing the service in the controller.

```
    services.AddScoped<AbstractsService>();
```

This is the reference in the Startup.cs for that project.

In the project where I'm receiving the error the ConfigureServices:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        DbHelper.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MeetingDataBase");
        services.AddAbstractOptions(Configuration);
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<Genetics.Lib.Common.GeneticsCommonOption>(Configuration);
        services.Configure<Genetics.Meeting.Abstracts.Options.RuntimeOption>(Configuration.GetSection("RuntimeOption"));
        services.AddGeneticsLists();

        //Areas
        Genetics.Meeting.Areas.AbstractReport.AbstractReportStartup.ConfigureServices(services);
        Genetics.Meeting.Areas.Program.ProgramStartup.ConfigureServices(services);

        services.AddScoped<Modules.ErrorReporter>();
        services.AddScoped<Filters.ErrorReporterSetupFilter>();

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc(option =>
        {
            option.Filters.Add(typeof(Filters.ErrorReporterSetupFilter));
        })
        .AddViewOptions(option =>
        {
            option.HtmlHelperOptions.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
        });
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    }
```

If I comment out all the code using the AbstractsService on the Abstract controller I then get this error.

```
    InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The 
    following locations were searched:
    /Views/Abstract/Index.cshtml
    /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

The view is located in the Abstract folder

Comment: `AbstractsService != AbstractService`. You are referring to both in your question. Is that a typo in your question, or in the code?

Comment: Also, is the class only *named* `Abstract` or is it actually declared as `abstract class`? You cannot instantiate an abstract class directly, only by subclassing it with a class that is not declared `abstract`.

Comment: @NightOwl888 yes thats a typo i have changed it now thank you. Yes the controller is called Abstract.