# Dependency Injection C#

Tags: c#

I am getting this error when I Debug : **"InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'AppOwnsData.Services.PowerBiServiceApi' while attempting to activate 'AppOwnsData.Controllers.HomeController'. "**

I have tried rewriting both the code in the Controller and Startup but still throwing the same error. Will appreciate help on this. Thanks!

**StartUp.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

        services.AddScoped(typeof(PowerBiServiceApi));

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options => {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
        services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    }
```

**HomeController.cs:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    private PowerBiServiceApi powerBiServiceApi;

    public HomeController(PowerBiServiceApi powerBiServiceApi)
    {
        this.powerBiServiceApi = powerBiServiceApi;
    }
```

**PowerBiServiceApi.cs:**

```
public class PowerBiServiceApi  {

    private ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition { get; }
    private string urlPowerBiServiceApiRoot { get; }

    public PowerBiServiceApi(IConfiguration configuration, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition) {
        this.urlPowerBiServiceApiRoot = configuration["PowerBi:ServiceRootUrl"];
        this.tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    }
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48908511/invalidoperationexception-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-while-attempting-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure PowerBiServiceApi to dependency injection before using it in your controller.
Now your PowerBiServiceApi needs urlPowerBiServiceApiRoot which for the sake of
reusable code should be made a config. You should abstract this string to an config class such as

```
    /// <summary>
    /// PowerBiOptions
    /// </summary>
    public class PowerBiOptions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Url to the powerbi service api
        /// </summary>
        public string UrlPowerBiServiceApiRoot { get; set; }
    }
```

This can then be configured in dependency injection as

```
 services.Configure<PowerBiOptions>(x =>
        {
            x.UrlPowerBiServiceApiRoot = Configuration["PowerBi:UrlPowerBiServiceApiRoot"];
        });
```

This can then be used in your PowerBiServiceApi constructor as

```
     public class PowerBiServiceApi
    {

        private readonly PowerBiOptions PowerBiOptions;
        private ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition { get; }

        public PowerBiServiceApi(IOptions<PowerBiOptions> PowerBiOptionsAccessor, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
        {
            this.PowerBiOptions = PowerBiOptionsAccessor?.Value;
            this.tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        }
    }
```

You can then pass more than one config for your PowerBiServiceApi without having it on your class constructor.

Comment: just for clarification, how do you modify these lines of code in the respective files? That is, Home Controller, Startup, and PowerBiServiceApi? I am still running into errors, this time syntax

Comment: First create the class PowerBiOptions as above, then in your ConfigureServices add the dependency injection for the PowerBiOptions as above, then finally edit your PowerBiServiceApi service as above. You might need to include usings (namespaces) for IOptions but after that you should be good to go

Comment: Finally worked. Thanks. I added the following usings (namespaces) for IOptions `using Microsoft.Extensions.Options` and `using System.Collections`

Comment: Also noticed I had Version conflict for .NET 5 and .NET 6. Repaired .NET 6 too as part of the solution.